# Babelfish for PostgreSQL schema issue vs SQL query and Pg/SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, babelfish

SQL function validated with babelfishCompass is not accessible via PostgreSQL.

I have a Babelfish cluster (multiple_db). I created the [dbo].[GetRef] function in SSMS, following the recommendation in the documentation, and after successful analysis by Babelfish Compass. When I call the function in SSMS on port 1433, it works fine. However, when I run the same function in PgAdmin on port 5432, the schema is not recognized, resulting in the error below:

[dbo].[GetRef] function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRef]
(   
    @Id bigint  
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, MUTID, FINID
    FROM [dbo].[Ref]
    WHERE ToBeInserted = 1 
    AND ID > @Id
    ORDER BY REFID
)
```

PostgreSQL query:
`SELECT MyDatabase_dbo.getref(1)`

PostgreSQL query error:

```
ERROR:  relation "dbo.ref" does not exist
LINE 2:  FROM [dbo].[Ref]
              ^
QUERY:  SELECT TOP 1 ID, MUTID, FINID
    FROM [dbo].[Ref]
    WHERE ToBeInserted = 1 
    AND ID > @Id
    ORDER BY REFID
CONTEXT:  PL/tsql function MyDatabase_dbo.getref(bigint) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

My understanding is that in principle, a function (or a stored procedure) written for SQL Server and migrated to Babelfish should be accessible and executable with PostgreSQL.

Is my understanding correct, or in my example, will the function run with PostgreSQL only if I change the schema from [dbo].[Ref] to MyDatabaseName_dbo.Ref ?
Since I have more than 3000 functions and stored procedures, should my external applications connect to the database via port 1433 or port 5432 ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to use valid SQL, no angled brackets. Connect with an interactive client like `psql` and look how the function is really called.

Comment: Same issue even when I create the table and the function without angled brackets ( create table dbo.ref , create function dbo.getref, and 'select ... from dbo.ref' within dbo.getref function body. I precise again that I use SSMS to create the table and the function, and then go to PSQL client to call the function.

Comment: Look in `psql` how the function is really called and in what schema it really is: `\df *.*ef`